# Custom google map in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, fluttermap

I am building a virtual tour app in Flutter. I want to add a widget that displays a map. Clicking on different spots on the map should directly take me to that spot in the tour. I have seen this feature in youvisit.com but I don't know how to implement it in Flutter. The widget in youvisit was a Google widget, but the map was custom, not like on Google Maps.
Thanks in advance.
[The map widget in youvisit.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBKfN.png)

I tried to find a way to create a custom map from scratch but didn't find anything like it.

Comment: You need to use google maps api to create custom 3d maps like that. Check out their api - https://developers.google.com/maps

Comment: Do you really need it in flutter? You can actually try it out with Maps Javascript using Web GL to build 3d maps. https://developers.google.com/codelabs/maps-platform/webgl#0